# How to read iPhone preferences from native application

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there any way I can read settings for iPhone preferences. I wanted to read whether the push notification flag is on or not. Based on this setting, I wanted to take some action in my native application. Please guide.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read settings for your application using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you are asking if you can read whether push notifications are on globally, then no, I don't think you can. If your application asks to use them, it will ask the user if they want to turn them back on, but that is all you can do.

Comment: My plan is to put my own application notification turn on/off but under device level notification on/off. So, user can go to Settings-->Notification and switch on/off my app's notification. I wanted to know this setting when my app is actually running. See the attached snapshot...

Comment: That switch goes in automatically when your app requests permission to use push notifications, but I don't think there is a way to check it's status.

Comment: Alright. What could be the alternative then? Should I use something in my app's settings i.e. inside my app I can provide a settings option wherein I can ask user to set whether to use push notification or not?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but there would still be no guarantee that the user didn't turn them off in the Settings app. Its better than nothing if you need to know though.